# I run python code for encryption from github. A lot of errors prevent me for executing it correctly

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to use this python code here, without success:

https://github.com/debajyotiguha11/PyCrypto

I run the script, but I  get these errors:

```
Do you want to (E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt? *Case Sensitive*
E
Enter the password:
abcd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pycrypto3.py", line 84, in <module>
    encrypt(SHA256.new(password).digest(), str(Tfiles))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 88, in new
    return SHA256Hash().new(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 75, in new
    return SHA256Hash(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py", line 72, in __init__
    HashAlgo.__init__(self, hashFactory, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.update(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py", line 69, in update
    return self._hash.update(data)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's basically one error (a `TypeError` exception), that's just a detailed traceback. You should be able to fix it if you encode `password`.

Comment: Thank you. How do I encode the password? I am very new on python...

Comment: With `password.encode()`, this converts the string to bytes. For more details see [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).